# How can I change an image by a video on hover

Tags: javascript

I would like to do something pretty similar to the netflix page on the browser.
I got an image, when it's hovered, its scale change but I would like to replace the image by a playing video with the song. I've tried to disable/enable on hovering but I got a problem: Its always the same video which is playing (surely because I've used the same id).
I've used JQuery to detect the hover then play the video, and a getElementById to get the video itself...
Here is my javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').hover(function(){
        Show()
        Play()
    }, function(){
        Pause()
        UnShow()
    });
});


const myVideo = document.getElementById("video");

function Play() {
    myVideo.play();
}

function Pause() {
    myVideo.pause();
}
```

And my HTML code:

```html
<body>
    <nav>
        <div class="logo"><h1>My Guitar Site</h1></div>
        <div class="search">
            <input type="text">
        </div>
    </nav>    
    
    <div class="ensemble">
        <div class="song">
            <a href="" class="a-song">
                <img src="Images/LetMeDownSlowly.jpg" alt="">
                <video id="video" width="120">
                    <source src="Video/test.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                  Your browser does not support the video tag.
                </video>
            </a>
            <h5 class="artistenom">Alec Benjamin - Let Me Down Slowly</h5>
            
        </div>
        <div class="song">
            <a href="" class="a-song">
                <img src="Images/CurduroyDreams.jpg" alt="">
            </a>
            <h5 class="artistenom">Rex Orange County - Corduroy Dreams</h5>
            <video id="video" width="120">
                <source src="Video/test2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
              Your browser does not support the video tag.
            </video>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Are you using HTML5 video player?

Comment: Yes, with a mp4 file.

Comment: Your HTML markup is different, so the a tag in the first video is wrapping the image and the video while the second only wraps the video. From the looks of this code there's a lot of steps missing. 1. You need references to all the videos like what you did with querySelectorAll 2. You have to loop through those references and find the one currently hovering over using event delegation. 3. Then after you have the correct video object, do the rest of what you are showing in your code.

Comment: Hi, the event delegation isn't just for "click"? But yess it worked thank you so much!!! I used this website in order to understand better event delegation [link](https://javascript.info/event-delegation) .  It's only working with an image for now but I have faith thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Im not big on jQuery but here's the general concept. You can add the poster attribute as follows. That should show the image.

```
<video controls poster="/images/cool-image.gif">
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg"
</video>
```

Assuming you have an event for hovering on and another for hovering off you can do the following:

***Hover on***
Play the video and remove the poster attribute:

```
function Play() {
    var poster = $(vid).attr("poster");

    $(vid).attr("poster","");

    myVideo.play();        
}
```

***Hover off***
Stop the video and add the poster attribute:

```
function Pause() {
    var poster = $(vid).attr("poster");

    $(vid).attr("poster", "poster.png");

    myVideo.pause();       
}
```

Again Im not a jQuery guy but generally I believe that will work.

Comment: Well first of all thanks for your answer the video is playing! But the problem with this (and the fact that every video get the same id, which is "#video") is thaht i have several images ( and videos) different, when I'm hovering one, it's aways the first video which is playing...

Comment: I apologize, its kinda hard to be able to come up with a verbatim solution with the lack of actually code to review.

Comment: Yes sorry my bad I understand, but that's actually ma whole js file. Would you like to see my html code? I know that a soloution which pop instantly doesn't exist, it will be too much easy, but i appreciate your help!

Comment: You should give each video a unique id. Like `<video id="video-1">..</video><video id="video-2">...</video>` then use a selector to get all the videos instead of `#video`

Comment: Thanks, with the querySelector('video'), the problem of the wrong video is gone (more or less, it's weird the detection shouldn"t happen) but the second video isn't playing.  With querySelectorAll('video') the video isn't playing but they are normally showing. Thanks for the help I'm struggling with this for almost 2 days arghhhh